# Handling routes with Chalice

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chalice

Chalice expects an `app.py` file with routes mapped to python function.
Using `chalice deploy` deploys these functions as AWS lambda and creates the route mapping in API Gateway.
I have to create a project with around 30 different route mappings. I could not find a way to keep routes for same resources separate from other resources i.e. I have to keep all the 30 mappings in the single file `app.py`. 
Is there anyway I can group routes belonging to same resource together and keep it in separate file? Something equivalent to controllers in Java world.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. You are welcome to give a thumbs up on the existing feature request to add [Routes in multiple python files](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/881) to Chalice.